# MVC3 - How to output a file to download without saving it on the server first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In PHP, it is possible to return a file to the browser by echoing it out with the correct header. You do not need to save a copy of it prior on the server.

So assuming I have a bunch of data I wish to return as a excel file - after creating the data structure using OpenXML, how can I serve the file to the user without saving it on the server first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write your data to a stream and return it from your controller action method in a [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx) by setting the `FileStream`, `ContentType` and `FileDownloadName` properties.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileStreamResult MyFile()
    {
        var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult (GetMyContentAsStream(), "my/content-type-here");
        fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = "my-file-download-name.here";

        return fileStreamResult ;
    }
```

**Update:**
A short cut for doing this, is to use the [Controller.File()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505200.aspx) method.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileStreamResult MyFile()
    {
        return File(GetMyContentAsStream(), "my/content-type-here");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, because the `FileStream` property is actually a `Stream` which `MemoryStream` derives from - `public Stream FileStream { get; private set; }`. You would pass the `MemoryStream` in the constructor though.

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty simple actually. In your controller you can have an action like this:

```
    public ActionResult GetMyFile()
    { 
        //dynamically generate a file
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms;
        ms = GenerateFile(); // Some function to return a memorystream object

        // return the file
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "filename.pdf");
    }
```

The user will be presented with a dialog box asking if they want to open the file or save it.

Comment: Actually, it can be even simpler than that. You don't need to call `.ToArray()` because `File` supports [an overload that takes a stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493017.aspx).

Comment: In my case, if I pass a stream, it complains: "ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream" even if the stream is open and positioned to 0. @GiddyUpHorsey, can you point to an example of using File(Stream)?

Comment: @Klaus - Is your stream in a `using` block?

Comment: @GiddyUpHorsey - No, I even checked that the stream is open and positioned to 0.

Comment: @Klaus - Without seeing your code, it is hard to tell what is wrong. It sounds like your stream is being disposed before `FileResult.ExecuteResult` has been executed by the MVC framework.

Comment: Ops. Disregard my comments. I had a nested zip-stream opened and closed through using()...

Answer (score 2):

You can save the contents of your dynamically generated file in a `MemoryStream` object. When you return a file you can use MemoryStream's `GetBuffer()` method to pass an array of bytes as the first parameter. Then set `ContentType` and `FileDownloadName` parameters.

Regards