# Downloading PDF file after creating it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have requirement in which i have to create a pdf file. This Pdf file contains some data and it. Now, the main requirement is that after i create the pdf, i should be able to download it. Now the PDF is getting created, But not being able to download it.
Please note that its an MVC application..
I am sharing the code for further reference

```
public class HoldFilesController : Controller
{
    // GET: HoldFiles
    string holdpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HoldPath"].ToString();
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(holdpath);

        List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles().ToList();

        return View("Index",files);
    }

     **The above controller gets filenames from a file directory**

    public ActionResult ViewFile(string[] Name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
        {
            string filepath=holdpath + @"\" + Name[i];

            string result;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
               Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

               PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
               document.Open();

               Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
               paragraph.Add(result);
               document.Add(paragraph);
               document.Close();
               byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
               memoryStream.Close();
               Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
               Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
filename=MyFile.pdf");
               Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/MyFile.pdf"));
               Response.End();
               Response.Close();

            }
        }
```

**The Above controller will get a filename, read the file and create pdf and 
download.** 
On debugging the code, i can see that document is created. But having 
trouble in downloading it

Comment: `But having trouble in downloading it` - Describe exactly what trouble you're having

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7088233/1662459

Comment: What's the binding between the created pdf and the response? You're not using filepath or anything in the response thing, what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
private FileResult ViewFile(string[] Name)
        {
         //create your file at filePath
           byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
           return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "MyFile.pdf"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using a random file name to download `MyFile` instead of using the file you just created. First of all, move the `Response` part outside the `using` and stop closing `MemoryStream` there, since the `using` block will do that for you when it finishes. So outside the `using` you should write something like:

```
// Create New instance of FileInfo class to get the properties of the file being downloaded
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);

// Checking if file exists
if (file.Exists)
{                            
    // Clear the content of the response
    Response.ClearContent();

    // LINE1: Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cance/save dialog to show, to the header
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", file.Name));

    // Add the file size into the response header
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

    // Set the ContentType
    Response.ContentType = ReturnFiletype(file.Extension.ToLower());

    // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
    Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

    // End the response
    Response.End();
}
```